# Is there anyway to get TreeNode that opened ContextMenuStrip in ToolStripMenuItem click handler?

Tags: c#, treeview, treenode, contextmenustrip

I have TreeView with different level TreeNodes
I added same ContextMenuStrip to all parent TreeNodes and i want to get possibility to delete all child TreeNodes by opening that ContextMenuStrip and pressing "Delete all"

```
private void btn_delete_all_objects_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ToolStripMenuItem tsmi = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender; //that way i receive button "Delete all"
    ContextMenuStrip cms = (ContextMenuStrip)tsmi.Owner; //this is ContextMenuStrip where this button...
    TreeView tw = (TreeView)cms.SourceControl; //i can get TreeView :( BUT I NEED TreeNode!
    TreeNode tn = tw.SelectedNode; //bah... if i select some of child nodes, then right click to open menu on parent, selected node is still that child
}
```

And i don't know how to get that TreeNode where user clicked to open menu
Any ideas?

Comment: You get the node, when the context-menu is shown. Just save this node in a variable and in the eventhandler read it.

Comment: which way? At contextMenuStrip1_Opening and contextMenuStrip1_Opened **sender** is still a ContextMenuStrip, but not a TreeNode

Comment: At the moment you do a mouse-click on a treenode you have the treenode. This u can save in a variable. After the click on an entry in the context-menu u can read the saved variable, which contains your node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `HitTest()` method from tree view to find the node, like this,

```
var hitTest = treeView1.HitTest(treeView1.PointToClient(new Point(contextMenuStrip1.Left, contextMenuStrip1.Top)));
if (hitTest.Node != null)
{
    // Place your code to delete nodes
}
```

or you can focus the node on which the mouse clicked and use `treeView1.SelectedNode` property to manipulate in your menu items. By this way you can avoid using HitTest() on every context menu item...

```
private void treeView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var hitTest = treeView1.HitTest(treeView1.PointToClient(e.Location));
    if (hitTest.Node != null)
    {
         treeView1.SelectedNode = hitTest.Node;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is working! thanks :) can't say this is really the best way, but if no other ways...

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what you are trying to do with the code above. But to do what you require (i.e. right click on `TreeNode` and launch a specific `ContextMenuStrip`) use code simalar to

```
private void customTreeViewSql_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
    // Ensure selected node is selected.
    treeView.BeginUpdate();
    this.treeView.SelectedNode = e.Node;
    try
    {
        if (e.Node.Level == 0)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
                contextMenuStripA.Show(MousePosition);
        }
        else if (e.Node.Level == 1)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
                contextMenuStripB.Show(MousePosition);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        this.treeView.EndUpdate();
    }
}
```

Then you can setup the click event in the ContexMenu to delete all child nodes based on that selected

```
private void toolStripMenuDeleteAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TreeNode treeNode = this.treeView.SelectedNode;
    foreach (TreeNode n in treeNode.Nodes)
        n.Remove();
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for trying to help, this is not what i wanted, but still... ContextMenuStrip shows automatically when click on TreeNode, i just needed the way to get what TreeNode opened that ContextMenuStrip when executing ToolStripmenuItem button press handler

Comment: The context button click event above fires immediately and will work for the currently selected node. This should do what you require.

Answer (score 2):

i think this is much clear and easy than Krishnakumar's code.
you can set your 'toolStripMenuDeleteAll' to some treenodes only and not to all of them.
this code don't change the Selected TreeNode At all.

welcome
CHADASH

```
TreeNode LastClickedTreeNode;
private void customTreeViewSql_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
    // update last treenode clicked.
    LastClickedTreeNode = e.Node;
}

private void toolStripMenuDeleteAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (TreeNode n in LastClickedTreeNode.Nodes)
        n.Remove();
}
```

Comment: I got the idea, but... It rely on mouse click. The node could be selected with keyboard arrow keys